# Android SQLite Database: Creating db at runtime or using prepopulated db?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm writing an app which will rely heavily on the use of a database. This database will have two "bigger" tables (50rows*70columns and 200rows*20columns) and 5 or 6 smaller tables. The app will need to access, read and edit the database.

Now, I'm having doubts about whether I should create the database programatically at runtime or using a prepopulated one on the assets folder. Considering the size of the database described in the first paragraph, which method do you think brings more advantages?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a fan of shipping my apps with a pre-populated database if the data is not dynamic.  Why parse a text file and do a bunch of inserts if you can just copy the database from your assets folder?

[Here is a guide to do it yourself](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)
[Here is a nice helper class if you would rather use proven code](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper)

Comment: The app will need to add some rows to the tables. Can I edit a prepopulated database?

Comment: absolutely, once you copy it over its the exact same as if you just created it programmically

Answer (score 1):

Prepopulated is the best practice in such conditions. [How to use the prepopulated database? see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9109728/265167).

Comment: The app will need to add some rows to the tables. Is it possible when using a prepopulated db? thanks

Comment: yes why not, see the link & you will find how to use the prepopulated database.